# How to make my flash file only responsive to key presses when certain objects are on the stage?

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I'm trying to make an object in my flash file only responsive to the keyboard when a certain object is on screen. However, with my current code (below), if you press and hold a key, it will allow you to go through the whole program. I want it to make you press the key anew each time the object enters the screen. (Program is in as2). Thank you!

```
leftbuttoninv.onEnterFrame = function() {
    if (Key.isDown(Key.LEFT)) {
        rotation_answer=answer_left;
        gotoAndPlay(2);
    }   
    else if (Key.isDown(Key.RIGHT)) {
        rotation_answer=answer_right;
        gotoAndPlay(2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple `if` statement to verify if your object exists :

```
leftbuttoninv.onEnterFrame = function() 
{
    if(your_object){
        if (Key.isDown(Key.LEFT)) {
            rotation_answer=answer_left;
            gotoAndPlay(2);
        }   
        else if (Key.isDown(Key.RIGHT)) {
            rotation_answer=answer_right;
            gotoAndPlay(2);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope that can help.